# AJAX submit form send in a weird way

Tags: php, ajax, forms

First of all, I'm a beginner. So, I have a form in Bootstrap 3.3.7. When clicked in the button "send message" should send automatically to the email directly from the site.

Although when I click "send message" it opens outlook(not sending directly from the site) and the message is:

```
name=Test&email=test%40hotmail.com&message=Test&submit=Send+Message
```

Does anyone know why this happens? 
Here's the code:

HTML:

```
    <form action="mailto:email@exemple.com?Subject=Exemple%20Contact" onsubmit="return submitForm();" method="post" name="contactform" class="contact-form wow zoomIn" data-wow-delay="0.6s" id="contact-form">
              <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-12">

                   <input placeholder="Name" class="input-field" name="name" required="" type="text">

                 </div>



                 <div class="col-md-12">
                   <input placeholder=" Email" class="input-field" name="email" required="" type="email"> 
                 </div>
               </div>
             </div>
             <div class="col-md-6">
               <textarea placeholder=" Message" class="input-field" name="message"></textarea> 
               <input value="Send Message" class="input-send submit" type="submit" name="submit">
             </div>




             <div class="col-md-12 send no-show hidden-xs"><button class=" botao btn btn-sucess"><h4 class="">Mensagem enviada com sucesso! Entraremos em contato brevemente!</h4></button></div>
      </form>


JS:

    function submitForm() {
        $.ajax({type:'POST', url:'email-action.php', data:$('#contact-form').serialize(),
         success: function(response) {
         $('.submit').html('send');
         $('.send').removeClass('no-show');
         document.contactform.reset();                                 
       }});                
        return false;

  }



PHP:

    $myemail = 'email@exemple.com';

    if (isset($_POST['name'])) {
    $name = strip_tags($_POST['name']);
    $email = strip_tags($_POST['email']);
    $message = strip_tags($_POST['message']);
    echo "Name:".$name."<br>";   
    echo "Email: ".$email."<br>"; 
    echo "Message: ".$message."<br>";

    $to = $myemail;
    $email_subject = "Contact from site";
    $email_body = "You have received a new message. ".
    " Here are the details:\n Name: $name \n ".
    "Email: $email\n Message \n $message";
    $headers = "From: $myemail\n";
    $headers .= "Reply-To: $email";
    mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you too confuse, just change the first line whit this:

```
<form action="" onsubmit="return submitForm();" method="POST" name="contactform" class="contact-form wow zoomIn" data-wow-delay="0.6s" id="contact-form">
```

The action is the URL where you send the data. If is the same URL, you can let it empty.

Is necessary put the method like this: method="POST" by default the method is GET and for that, the data appears in your URL

Now, in PHP you can get the parameters POST in the array `$_POST['someKey']`, or if you need the parameters in your URL (like  "name=Test&email=test%40hotmail.com&message=Test&submit=Send+Message") use `$_GET['otherKey']`.

Is too basic this, you should study some tutorials about PHP [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com) is a good web page whit a lot of courses.

Good Luck, and sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Ok! yeah, is pretty confuse like i am haha.
Thank you so much!